# MSRP missing on Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, msrp

I've migrated a store from M1 to M2 and on the M1 store MSRP is used extensively. Problem I have is when I open advanced pricing on a product I don't see the field MSRP on any of the products.
[image: advanced pricing]

I've seen some posts saying that you have to enable MAP, but that doesn't enable msrp

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable "MAP" Minimum Advertised Price to see it.

You can enable the same from

> Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> MAP.

Here is the URL from where you can find more details about the same.

> http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-price-minimum-advertised.html

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes - I was trying to enable MAP per store. That doesn't work. You need to enable MAP globally. Now need to figure out why M! values haven't migrated